# Push Notifications Ionic

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

First of all, I'm developing a proyect in Ionic (front-end), Node.js + Express (backend) and MongoDB as DB and, I want to implement push notification in my app. I've read a lot about notification using firebase but I'm using MongoDB. I'm quite lost if anyone could help/guide me, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Firebase push or Firebase cloud messaging with your app without any issue. It is just one service of Firebase family. You don't need to use its real-time database with your app. You just need to integrate Firebase cloud messaging service only. i.e. you can keep Mongodb backend as it is now.

Article about [Firebase Push and Ionic 4](https://www.djamware.com/post/5c6ccd1f80aca754f7a9d1ec/push-notification-using-ionic-4-and-firebase-cloud-messaging)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use firebase and/or you want push notifications even if you are offline, there is this Cordova plugin you can use: [cordova-plugin-local-notifications](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications).
[Quick instructions here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications). Not-so-quick instructions: read the documentations and issues in github.

Install like this:

```sh
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-local-notification
npm install @ionic-native/local-notifications
```

Then import and include the provider in `app.module.ts` (don't forget this step, usually not included in any manual):

```js
import {LocalNotifications} from '@ionic-native/local-notifications/ngx';
...
providers: [ LocalNotifications ]
```

Then import and inject in `your_page.page.ts`:

```js
import {LocalNotifications} from '@ionic-native/local-notifications/ngx';
...
constructor(private localNotifications: LocalNotifications) {}
```

And finally use it like this:

```js
this.localNotifications.schedule({
    title: 'My first notification',
    text: 'Thats pretty easy...',
    foreground: true
});
```

Test it thoroughly, the plugin is not bugfree, but works.

Hope this helps.